# Preferential Attachment, Complex Networks in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, complex-networks

Hej everyone!

I am right now working on a preferential attachment model in MATLAB and I have some troubles to understand the following:

Assuming I have 4 nodes in the beginning, connected like this:

```
time = 0  
1 <-----> 2  
3 <-----> 4
```

In the next time step I add a single node and 4 connections, then another single node and 4 connections.
The formula for my linking probability to node i is:

```
P_link(i) = degree(i) / sum of all degrees at time-1
```

This results in the probabilities of 1/4 for each of the nodes i = 1 to 4 in the first step and then, having node 5 connected to 1, 2, 3 and 4, I will have a "sum of degrees" = 12, when adding node 6 in the following time step.
That then means the linking probabilities are: 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6 and 1/3.

How can I set this up in MATLAB? My problem is, I normally write these things on paper to get a better understanding, and if there is a randomisation I just "simulate" it on paper to compare it with a simple MATLAB program.

What I would now do is: I take a random number, let's say 0.3045.
To add this to a node it would have to be in the range of

```
node1: [0.0000, 1/6],  
node2: [1/6, 1/3],  
node3: [1/3, 1/2],  
node4: [1/2, 2/3],  
node5: [2/3, 1.0000].  
---> CONNECT to node2
```

So for the first step I have an idea of how to do it, but now I have two different problems, which are, I think, closely related:

1. How am I able to implement this in MATLAB, is the range approach a good idea?
2. How do the probablities change after adding the first connection for the rest, assuming it can only be connected once to each node? (this might be a more mathematical question I have to admit ...)

I am very sorry, this question looks so messy, but I hope someone can give me some hints about the implementation of this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your list of already connected nodes implemented?

Comment: I think it is called "connectivity matrix":  
Basically A = [0 1 0 0; 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1; 0 0 1 0];  
But this was, because before I worked on randomly created networks and MATLAB offers this "graph"-function for connectivity matrices.

Comment: OK, lets start... for your function computing out- `degree(i)` I would use `sum(A(i, :))`. If the graph is linked bidirectionally all the time, you can calculate the total degree of `A` like so: `sum(sum(A)) / 2`.

Comment: Am I going in the right direction? Or did I misunderstand your problem? I guess, that you are asking for help on how to do your thing in Matlab right?

Comment: You are right. This is how I calculate the degree (have a histogram for example in the random network for example). And yes that is it: I can implement it in whatever language I want to, but I am most experienced in MATLAB, just not in this field of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following...

Having your Adjacency matrix

```
>> A = [0 1 0 0; 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1; 0 0 1 0]
```

and Degrees matrix

```
>> D = sum(A)
```

In every iteration, the degree of any vertex `i` is `D(i)` and total number of degrees is

```
>> d = sum(D)
```

Note, that you want to obtain `d` prior to the first iteration, and then again at the very end of iteration loop, so that it remains with value of `time-1`, in which case you might want to normalize `P` by doing

```
>> P = P ./ max(P)
```

Probabilities of picking any vertex (ie. your range approach simplified) are then calculated

```
>> P = cumsum(D ./ d)
ans = [0.2500, 0.5000, 0.7500, 1.0000]
```

And with random scalar number `r` from range `<0,1>`, you choose index `i` of randomly selected vertex by

```
>> i = find([-1 P]<r, 1, 'last')
```

And to push the new vertex with index `j` to `A`, connecting it to old vertex `i`, you simply

```
>> A(i, j) = 1
>> A(j, i) = 1
```

Now you simply enclose everything in [loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html) and voilà you problem solved ;]

Comment: Thanks! I am honestly everytime astonished by the amount of functions MATLAB does provide! A question though: you wrote `[-1 Pd]<r`. I know what `find` does, but I can not get what the meaning of the `[-1 Pd]` is.

Comment: That is a typo, I corrected it. Should be `[-1 P]<r`, which simply adds another cell with probability less then 0 in front of the simplified range `P`. This way you don't need redundant column for your range, and you are able to use this in one-liner.

Comment: This was an almost perfect introduction/explanation into the MATLAB tools mentioned! The "mathematical-algorithm-whatever"-part I will definitely manage to put together from this on. Thank you very much!